# Book recommendation for connection between immigration and crime

Tags: immigration, europe, crime

I'd like to know a little bit more about the reasons behind the migration flows to Europe, especially in recent years, and the (eventual) connections with (organized) crime, especially in Southern Europe. I'm thus looking for a book which explains the historical, political and/or economical reasons behind this phenomenon. It's a delicate topic and I know there's a lot of misinformation around it, especially when it comes to the relation between migrants and crime.

Comment: Much of it is people fleeing the wars in Afghanistan, Syria, Libya - something like half the population of Syria is displaced, mostly to Turkey.

Comment: I find this question confusing.  Do you want a book recommendation discussing migration flows to Europe?  Or a book discussing a connection between immigration and crime in Europe?

Comment: Is this question really too broad? There might be books about this topic? Maybe the asker could additionally specify which level these books should be. More like academic discourses of the topic or more like digestible for everyone but maybe less scientific?

Comment: What is the general policy of politics.stackexhange for book recommendations? They tend to get outdated. Next year there might be better books on the market.

Comment: @Trilarion That would be a good question to ask on [meta], if you'd be so inclined.

Comment: I'm not really able to limit my question to a specific problem/topic, since I just now got interested in this topic... If it's too broad, you can close it.

Comment: @wrong_path If you cannot really narrow the search down then maybe a search engine could be a valid alternative. Google may be able to give you some books.